# .well-known/acme-challenge nginx 404 error

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to verify a file upload for SSL certificate.
The file needs to be `.well-known/acme-challenge/file`

I have successfully placed the file as above, but while accessing the same file from the web `http://weburl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/file`, 404 error is coming up.
When I place the same file in `.well-known/` the file can be access from the path `http://weburl.com/.well-known/file` successfully.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name weburl.com; 
        root /var/www/html;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri =404;
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grant permissions for www-data user.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .well-known
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case it looks for `/var/www/html/.well-known/file`.

In the second case it looks for `/var/www/html/file`.

What you intend is for it to find `/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/file`

This is because you specify `root` in the `location` block, which changes where it reads the file from.

So instead of this:

```
    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html; # <================= Your problem, sir
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
    }
```

You should have this:

```
    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
    }
```

Shameless plug: If you're just doing simple virtual hosting and you're familiar with node at all you might like [Greenlock](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js).

Comment: The root directive here, although unnecessary as it's identical to the one already defined at server level, is perfectly valid. The actual problem is when Nginx is checking for regex matches it selects the first matching location block to handle the request, and as the location block listed before this is defined with regex which will match any requests that would also match this block then Nginx will always select the previous location, making this block totally redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the LetsEcnrypt module on Plesk, but for some reason you need to authorize for eg. example.com manually like we do.

Add you authorization code to
`/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/.well-known/acme-challenge`
instead of expected (domain webroot)
`/var/www/vhosts/example.com/htdocs/.well-known/acme-challenge`

To find so I had to check `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/httpd.conf`